# Running ubuntu netbook edition and desktop edition together on the same machine

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

Currently I have installed desktop edition on my netbook. But it feels a little slower for me. So I want to try out netbook edition by having it along with the desktop edition. So are there any problems if both appear together in the grub2 menu, or is there anything else which might cause issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-netbook
```

Then reboot and select Unity (or Netbook) from GDM login screen

Answer (score 2):

What I would do, is just install gnome along side Unity, so at the login screen it gives you the choice of which envirment you want to use. This can easily be done by running the command `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-netbook` in the terminal after it completes the install, you log off and select the user, and then under session select Ubuntu Desktop Edition. And log on as you normally wouldsudo apt-get install ubuntu-netbook